# Отступ перед строкой

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

Возникла проблема с расположением элементов на странице.

Вот моя верстка:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <div id="headTableProceeds">
      <table class="table table-bordered" style="margin: 0; table-layout: fixed">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th id="sel" style="display: none">Продавец</th>
            <th id="auto" style="display: none">Автомобиль</th>
            <th id="proceeds" style="display: none">Выручка</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div id="bodyTableProceeds" class="container">
      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tbody></tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        @Html.Label("Фильтры детализации:")
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        @Html.CheckBox("По дате")
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group">
          @Html.Label("С", new { @style = "margin-right: 5px" })
          <input type="date" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          @Html.Label("По", new { @style = "margin-right: 5px" })
          <input type="date" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

`lable` и `input type="checkbox"` идут с самого начала без отступов.

А вот `lable` который идёт перед `input-ом` с типом `date` делает отсутп, так как перед ним появляется ***псевдоэлемент `before`***.

Но если я например сделаю **2** `input` с типом `date`, которые у меня в коде не в **1** ряд, а каждый с новой строки, тогда `before` тоже будет, но отступов уже не будет. Подскажите пожалуйста как можно избавиться от отступов?

Вот скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: присмотритесь к колонкам, Bootstrap нету служебного класса col (нужно указать цифру, например col-sm-12)

Comment: @slowBro не в них проблема, col работает нормально, проблема как раз в следующих, где есть col-sm-4 и col-sm-6

Comment: @slowBro а, оказывается помогло выставить значение col'ам, спасибо большое.

Comment: дело в том что просто col не имеет паддингов(оступов) а col-<sm>-* имеет паддинг в 15 пикселей. советую вам почитать про сетку в Bootstrap для понимания для чего нужнеа стуркутра container->row->col https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid

Comment: @slowBro спасибо